# Volume of intersection between a ball and a solid cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, volume

Let $B_{R_1} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be the ball of radius $R_1 > 0$ centred at the origin. 
Let $C_{R_2,d}$ the solid cylinder with radius $R_2 > 0$ and with axis at distance $d$ from the origin. For instance 
$$
C_{R_2, d} = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : (x - d)^2 + y^2 \le R_2^2\}.
$$

Is there a formula to compute the volume of $B_{R_1} \cap C_{R_2, d}$ as function of $R_1, R_2, d$?

Comment: There are several cases you need to consider, but one can derive a formula for each of them, at least write it down as an integral. Not sure you can solve the integral. Numerically should be trivial.